# Multi user 'guess a number' game with sockets, using C

Tags: c, sockets

I'm having problems finishing my program using sockets in C. It's a basic 'guess a number' game.  The problem is that once a number is guessed correctly, the client console doesn't output anything that it is supposed to ("You won" and "Keep on guessing next number").

Sample code from `Client.c`:

```
while (1) {
    bzero(buffer,BUF_SIZE);
    scanf("%s", &buffer);
    send_line(sockfd, buffer);

    if (strcmp(buffer, "quit") == 0)
        break;

    recv_line(sockfd, buffer);
    printf("Server: %s\n", buffer);

    if (strcmp("Bingo!", buffer) == 0) {
        printf("You won!!");
        recv_line(sockfd, buffer);
        printf("Server: %s\n",buffer);
        printf("Keep on guessing next number!\n");
    }
}
```

Sample code from `Server.c`:

```
while (1) {
    recv_line(new_fd, buffer);
    printf("%s\n",buffer);
    if (strcmp(buffer, "quit") == 0) {
        printf("Client '%s' quit.\n", name);
        break;
    }
    if (atoi(buffer) >lol){
        send_line(new_fd,"number too big!");
        }
        if (atoi(buffer) <lol){
            send_line(new_fd,"number too small!");
        }               
        if (lol== atoi(buffer)){
            send_line(new_fd, "Bingo!");
            printf("Client '%s' guessed correctly!\n ", name);
            printf("Enter new number fo user '%s'!\n", name);
            scanf("%d", &lol);
            send_line(new_fd, "New number generated!");
        }
    }
}
```

also:

```
void send_line(int new_fd, char * buffer) {
    int len = strlen(buffer);

    if (send(new_fd, buffer, len, 0) == -1) {
        perror("send");
        exit(1);
    }
}

void recv_line(int new_fd, char * buffer){
    int len;

    if ((len = recv(new_fd, buffer, BUF_SIZE, 0)) == -1){
        perror("recv");
        exit(1);
    } else
        buffer[len] = '\0';    
}
```

How can I make this work after the user has guessed correctly?

Comment: What is the output of the line printf("Serveris: %s\n", buffer);? Does the buffer by chance include a newline? Try printf("Serveris: **%s**\n", buffer)  so you know the exact contents of the buffer

Comment: did u test if anything that is send from the server reaches client?

Comment: what is recv_line? and send_line. Did you use a debugger to watch whats happening?

Comment: It just prints out "Bingo!" and hops into new line, then nothing happens...

Comment: Seems that the lines "Bingo!" and "Client guessed correclty" from the Client.c get printed ONLY after entering new number in Server.c (right after when client guesses the number correctly)

Comment: seems like a flushing problem

Comment: Strings "number too big" or "number too small" get printed out when needed and correctly, all that is failing is once the number is guessed correctly --> string "Bingo!" from Server.c goes to Client.c and then nothing happens until you put in a new number in Server.c

Answer (score 0):

> Strings "number too big" or "number too small" get printed out when needed and correctly, all that is failing is once the number is guessed correctly --> string "Bingo!" from Server.c goes to Client.c and then nothing happens until you put in a new number in Server.c

This is exactly how the client is coded:

```
if (strcmp("Bingo!", buffer) == 0) {
    printf("You won!!");
    recv_line(sockfd, buffer);
    printf("Server: %s\n",buffer);
    printf("Keep on guessing next number!\n");
}
```

`stdio` is line-buffered. Losely speaking it means that the data remain in the internal buffer until a newline character is printed. So the `You won!!` (having no newline character) string is *printed*, but not *flushed*, until `printf("Server: %s\n",buffer)` supplies the newline.

Change `printf("You won!!")` to `printf("You won!!\n")` or call `fflush(stdout)` after it.

Comment: Holy smokes! Newer thought this detail would make such a difference... Thank you a lot!